# How to output html tag as part of string content to div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have variable "htmlElement" which has the format like `<p class="Day">Test Message</p>`

What I am going to do is to output the content of htmlElement as a string to the div which has a class panel-body.

What I did is `$(".panel-body").append(htmlElement);`

But in the div.panel-body, user can only see `Test Message`, the other part has been treated as html tag.

The question is , how could I let the div.panel-body show `"<p class=Day>Test Message</p>"`

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do this? `$(".panel-body").text(htmlElement);`

Comment: @kukac67 That will work if `.panel-body` is empty because it replaces content not append content.

Comment: Yes that will work only if .panel-body is empty, I want to append content to it, not replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
$(".panel-body").append(document.createTextNode(htmlElement));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9z3zE/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what you have stored in variables already, but if you have `<p class=Day>Test Message</p>` stored in a string variable, you can do this:

```
$(".panel-body").text(variable);
```

(As **Musa** said, this replaces the content.)

To add, do:

```
$(".panel-body").append("<p class=Day>Test Message</p>");
```

or

```
$(".panel-body").prepend("<p class=Day>Test Message</p>");
```